# Create responsive html element relative to its own width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Everytime i work on a responsive design I wonder why all media queries are fixed on the screens width/height. Why not the width/height of an element? Is this possible?

When making reusable html elements in a somewhat modular way, it seems logical to 'scale/design' it relative to it's own width and not the screens width. This way you only have to design the HTML/CSS once and you can use it in different sections of your page without needing to add extra media queries.

Obviously there are workarounds, but is there a css-only way to add css rules depending on it's own or parents width/height?

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: Because the differentiating factor between different screens and devices is the screen dimensions. The dimensions of the elements should, then, adjust *according to* those variable screen dimensions.

Comment: @Mitya The main problem is how to develop reusable web components. In this case you can not rely on the screen's dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContainerQueries A.K.A. ElementQueries are still waiting to be implemented natively in CSS. I think this is very sad, but it doesn't look like that it does any progress for years now.